# Lookbehind in date regex (python)

Tags: python, regex, date

I am having some trouble figuring out the look-behind in Python. More specifically I have this piece of text which has dates in `(mm/dd/yyyy)` `(mm-dd-yyyy)` formats and just the years in `(yyyy)` formats :

```
Jan-01-2001
Jan 01 2001
2003 2007
The year was 2009 when x decided to work for Google
```

What is the best way of matching to just extract the lines which have the  `yyyy`. I should be able to extract `2003` , `2007` and `2009` but not any other dates like the `Jan-01-2001` and `Jan 01 2001`. I tried the *lookbehind* operator and the best I could come with was `((?<!(-| ))\d{4})`. But this selects only `2003` and **not** `2007` and `2009`. I also tried using *groups* to define a date pattern and use them in conjunction with *lookbehind*, but that did not work. What would be the right and efficient way of doing this in regular expressions (Python)

Comment: Easiest method is probably to identify dates and then just capture what doesn't match (or partially match) a date: `\b\d{1,2}[ -]\d{4}|(\d{4}\b)` - grab capture group 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

This only works with the sample strings you've presented (and where the year is not preceded by 2 digits followed by a space or hyphen). Assuming that all dates use 2 digit numbers to define a day of the month, this will work for you (since lookbehinds in python (and the majority of regex engines) cannot be quantified).

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/RDoAoh/3)

```
\b(?<!\b\d{2}[ -])\d{4}\b
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Jan-01-2001
Jan 01 2001
2003 2007
The year was 2009 when x decided to work for Google
```

#### Output

```
2003
2007
2009
```

---

### Explanation

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?<!\b\d{2}[ -])` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes doesn't match the following

  - `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
  - `\d{2}` Match exactly 2 digits
  - `[ -]` Match either a space  or hyphen `-` character
- `\d{4}` Match exactly 4 digits
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @ctwheels. It was helpful. You are right. Obviously if I had a sentence like, `The year is 2009 and I decided to work for Google on 01-Jan-2004`, this wouldn't work.  I would need that to work as well. I'll try modifying your regex to include `\w{3}`.

Comment: @N00bsie you'd have to add a new negative lookbehind for each possibility such as: `\b(?<!\b\d{2}[ -])(?<!\b[A-Z][a-z]{2}[ -])\d{4}\b`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies @ctwheels. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope this may help you:

import re
string = """Jan-01-2001
Jan 01 2001
2003 2007 
The year was 2009 when x decided to work for Google"""
for year in string.split('\n'):
    search_date = re.search(r'^(?!\w{3}(?:\s+|-)\d{2}(?:\s+|-)\d{4}).+',year)
    if search_date:
      print(re.findall(r'\d{4}',search_date.group()))
```

Comment: No that doesn't. I am looking for a regular expression with a lookbehind that will allow me to capture only those strings that have just the year in them. What you have given will capture all years (i.e. even if they are part of the (mm-dd-yyyy) or (mm/dd/yyyy) format. Your regex is `\d{4}`. It will select any four digits.

Comment: @N00bsie I have re-edited my answer please check it.may be it help you now